# "Issue with PDF Attachments: Unable to Display Data in Gmail Client" CSHARP

Tags: c#, gmail, email-attachments, html2pdf

I am facing an issue when sending an email with an attachment in C# using the SmtpClient. The email is successfully delivered to Gmail, but when I open the attachment in the Gmail client, there is no data shown.

```
 using (var stream = file.OpenReadStream())
 {
    var attachment = new Attachment(stream, file.FileName);  
    mailMessage.Attachments.Add(attachment);
    Client.Send(mailMessage);
    attachment.Dispose();  
 }
```

Checked the generated PDF file independently to ensure data is present.
Examined the email content to verify that it includes the expected data.
Debugged the C# code to confirm that the attachment is being added to the email correctly.
Reviewed Gmail client settings to check if there are any specific requirements for displaying attachments.

**Expectation:**
I expected the Gmail client to display the data in the attachment as intended. However, despite the email being sent successfully, the attachment appears empty when opened in the Gmail client.

Comment: Why do you have three streams? Why not just use the first one to create the `Attachment` and then close it after sending the message? Get rid of the two `MemoryStreams` and the `byte` array altogether.

Comment: i removed all other stream and used the orginal stream . but now i got exception of 500 
object dispostion now the email not sending . i have less experience working with files psl suggest me good way

Comment: Ugh! I specifically said to close the stream after sending the message. You are closing it immediately after creating the attachment and the code to send the message is not shown, so it must be being done afterwards. You should be creating the attachment with a `using` statement too and then sending the message inside the `using` block. The objects are disposed at the end of the block, so the attachment and the stream.

Comment: still the data in the pdf are not showing when i open the attachment in gmail client its blank 4 page pdf file

Comment: stream is not fully copied to attachment ? that's why pdf is blank?

Comment: If you save the data from `file.OpenReadStream` to a local file, does that file look the way it should? BTW, I've said twice now that you should be disposing the `Attachment` and you still aren't doing so. That should have no effect on this issue but it's still something you should be doing.